# How to change the default URL into custom URL in Mendix?

Tags: url, mendix

Can any one please tell me that how change the default URL (Example: http://localhost:8081/index.html?profile=Responsive ) into a Custom URL(Example: http://localhost:8081/UserName/) without any license in locally or cloud Mendix(Low-code platform)?

**NOTE:** UserName in the sense logged user’s Name.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please note that I need achieve this in Mendix.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the widget Set Url from the Appstore. https://appstore.home.mendix.com/link/app/65083/
This allows for dynamic url's. Also checkout the DeepLink module from the Appstore for more possibillities.